# How can I determine exactly when a startup process loaded in relation to other processes after logging in?

Tags: process, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1

I have an end user system that requires certain software/processes to start in a specific order upon logging in.  These processes aren't managed services so I can't set an extended delay for the one I want to run last.  I suspect that things aren't actually starting in the correct order but I'm not sure how i can confirm.

So my question is: are there Windows audit logs or tools that can tell me when exactly a given process was launched in relation to other processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Process Monitor and Process Explorer from Microsoft Sysinternals will give you a "Life Time" for each process, which tracks when a process was started relative to other processes, so you can see which processes were just started versus ones that have been running for a long time.

[image: Process Monitor]

Without using any external tools, you can also simply enable Process Tracking Auditing with Group Policy (or secpol.msc/Local Security Policy.) And it will log to the Security event log any time a process is launched or exited on the entire system.

[image: Process Tracking]

If the process in question is wrapped inside of an svchost.exe service hosting process, however, it's a little trickier.  You would need to figure out which instance of svchost.exe hosts the process, then split the service out into individual processes by using `sc config servicename Type= own` as seen [here](http://networkdirection.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95:splitting-svchost-processes&catid=36:microsoft&Itemid=63) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistanow/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-separate-out-dll-based-services-that-use-a-shared-generic-service-host-process-name-svchost-exe-for-troubleshooting.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed to know.  For others who may be wondering - the columns for `Process Timeline` / `Start Time` in process explorer are not enabled by default and can be added via View -> Select Columns -> Process Performance (tab).